# Selecting which columns appear in a GridView control

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Hi I have created a dataset to a gridview, when it runs it is showing all of the columns in the dataset, I would like to control which columns it displays; however, when I click on edit columns in the designer it is not showing me any columns to edit.  When  I use an SQLDataSource control and choose that as my data set I can see and select all columns that I want to see.  How can I code this without using the SqlDataSource control?

```
SqlConnection PTConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Project_Tracker"].ConnectionString);
SqlCommand PTCmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from tbl_Projects", PTConn);
SqlDataAdapter PTda = new SqlDataAdapter(PTCmd);
DataSet PTds = new DataSet();
PTda.Fill(PTds);

GridView1.DataSource = PTds;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either handle the [RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Cells[index].Visible = false;
}
```

or, you can set the [AutoGenerateColumns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogeneratecolumns%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to `false` and create either [templated custom columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288032.aspx) or DataBound Columns:

```
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="field1" HeaderText="Field1" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="field2" HeaderText="Field2" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="field3" HeaderText="Field3" />
    ...
</Columns>
```

The final option, is to modify your SQL statement to explicity `SELECT` the fields you need instead of selecting `*`:

```
SqlCommand PTCmd = new SqlCommand("Select field1, field2, field3 from tbl_Projects", PTConn);
```

However, if you need, for example, the ID, then the latter probably isn't an option. I think the first option would be the easiest and fastest to implement.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the individual columns, you have to explicitly select the fields you want to see rather than using `SELECT *`. That's what I've done before.

Answer (score 0):

The designer is intended to be used with a "known" data source **at** design time. You cannot use the designer to edit a GridView field list when the data source is programmatically assigned.